# Unable to set scale on QgsLayoutItemMap

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have made manually one layout in QGIS 3.10, I access it using PyQGIS and I want to add a new `QgsLayoutItemMap`. I'm unable to set scale correctly. Does I miss a step? Is it a bug? Are you able to reproduce?

```py
layout1 = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layouts()[0]

qgsLayoutItemMap2 = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout1)
qgsLayoutItemMap2.setId('myNewId')
qgsLayoutItemMap2.attemptSetSceneRect(QRectF(10, 10, 180, 180))
qgsLayoutItemMap2.setFrameEnabled(True)
qgsLayoutItemMap2.setFrameStrokeColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
layout1.addItem(qgsLayoutItemMap2)

print(qgsLayoutItemMap2.scale()) # Return 0.0
qgsLayoutItemMap2.setScale(40000.0)
print(qgsLayoutItemMap2.scale()) # Return nan
```

The second return e.g `nan` after setting scale seems anormal.
Any clue? I want to use the project and not layers to control the display in the `QgsLayoutItemMap` contrary to [this test code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgslayoutmap.py#L217) (see `qgsLayoutItemMap2.keepLayerSet()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue just five minutes after posting...

```py
layout1 = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layouts()[0]

qgsLayoutItemMap2 = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout1)
qgsLayoutItemMap2.setId('myNewId')
qgsLayoutItemMap2.attemptSetSceneRect(QRectF(10, 10, 180, 180))
qgsLayoutItemMap2.setFrameEnabled(True)
qgsLayoutItemMap2.setFrameStrokeColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
extent = QgsRectangle(-122.52, 37.71, -122.35, 37.83)
qgsLayoutItemMap2.setExtent(extent)
layout1.addItem(qgsLayoutItemMap2)

print(qgsLayoutItemMap2.scale()) # Return 60835.889859339615
qgsLayoutItemMap2.setScale(40000.0)
print(qgsLayoutItemMap2.scale()) # Return 39999.999999998035
```

The clue has been found in code from https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/pyqgis-in-a-day.html#creating-a-pdf-with-title
You need to set an extent to avoid the issue I've encountered.